# how can I request openai api in docker container through vpn?

Tags: openai-api

I have encountered a problem: My VPN can only be used on Windows and there is no client for Linux. Now, I have installed a virtual machine on Windows, which runs CentOS 7 and has Docker containers. These Docker containers need to access OpenAI's API. However, I am constantly getting network errors and cannot make requests. How can I solve this problem?